# Image overlay when painting mask

Tags: compositing-nodes, texture-painting, masking

I'd like to correct local exposure in compositor so I've set up multiply node with main image and mask image. All works fine, but I'd like to show main image as overlay or instead of mask image - like painting on main image but strokes should come to mask image. Similar to photoshop painting on adjustment layer - adjustment layer is not visible only correction is. Is it possible to do it in blender?